# Cross platform .NET WebSocket server library with async support

Tags: .net, mono, websocket, async-await, supersocket.net

Are there any cross-platform (read: Mono-friendly) libraries that offer WebSocket server support and allow for asynchronous IO via a C# 5 `async` API?

[SuperSocket.NET](http://supersocket.codeplex.com/) seems like the closest option, but does [not appear to offer async support](http://docs.supersocket.net/v1-6).

Mono itself [does not yet implement](http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.5&profile=4.5&assembly=System) `System.Net.WebSockets`.

Comment: You can run XSockets.NET on Mono and there are async send methods but not with C#5. XSockets is built on .NET 4.0
http://xsockets.net

Comment: [Alchemy Websockets](http://alchemywebsockets.net) is another Mono-compatible WebSocket library, but it doesn't appear to have async support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use now [WebSocketListener](http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/).

It offers async methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SuperWebSocket instead of SuperSocket.
Both SuperWebSocket and SuperSocket support async communications.
SuperWebSocket is a websocket server base on SuperSocket.

Comment: Can you provide a reference that shows how these libraries support c# 5 `async`?

Comment: It doesn't support the keyword "async", but the communications is async.

Comment: My question is about support for C# 5's `async` and `await`.